# Invoke Excel UDF from Workbook Macro

Tags: c#, excel, vba, excel-dna

I can create Excel User Defined Functions using [ExcelDNA](http://exceldna.codeplex.com/).  Is it possible to invoke them from a Workbook Macro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup it sure is:) Take a look at this: http://exceldna.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Integrating%20with%20VBA&referringTitle=Documentation

Comment: ExcelDNA.Integration.CustomUI.ExcelComAddIn has to be updated to ExcelDNA.Integration.ExcelComAddIn.